# Test not appearing in dropdown

Tags: stb-tester

Trying to test the stb-tester, but the test I have made I have pushed to the box, go to the stb-tester git and it's there, but it is not available in the dropdown to run. How do you get the test into the test dropdown to choose it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a test to show up on the stb-tester web-UI test-selection box

1. The test must be in a Python file (ending `.py`)
2. This file must be in the test repo under the `tests/` directory
3. The name of the test function should begin with `test_`

Comment: Nope that doesn't work. In fact my files are now not showing up in the stb repo even though it is pushing to the correct place.

Comment: Nope, that was me being a chump, I renamed the file not the function. Renaming the function to "test_first" worked fine.